# Flash Player is not working in domain, but working if i provided IP

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, crossdomain.xml

I have developed a player in AS3. It is working if i provide the IP of the website. But, it is not working when i provide the full domain name. Even, i provide the crossdomain.xml for global access.

Please suggest.

Comment: please provide your code exerpt, xml, and the error you get.

Comment: The Player loads in page, but all the controls and functionality is not working.. The functionality of the player is same as youtube player, the player start playing the video once it loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
import flash.system.Security;
Security.allowDomain("*");
```